# Is there a way to open a file and prevent flushing updates to hardware unless I command it to?

Tags: linux, mmap

I know for kernel functions `open()`, `mmap()` and `msync()` and what they do. But no matter what combination of flags I attempt to use, the kernel will either still flush updates using some of its own time intervals or it won't flush at all (in case I map it with `MAP_PRIVATE`). I hope I am wrong. Is there a way to fully control when flushes do and do not happen? I want to map a file, do some changes and **only** flush it when I decide to and not earlier! Is it possible?

Comment: I guess the simple solution would be to keep a private copy of the data in memory and then `memcpy()`and `msync()` it into the memory area mapped from the file. (or just `write()`). That shouldn't take _too_ long unless your data is _huge_ (and then you could add some data structure to add the "dirty" parts)

Comment: @ilkkachu Thank you for suggestions. I will explore then the idea with ```memcpy``` becuase on the man-page for ```msync``` it says it does nothing if I mapped memory privately. And yeah, I plan to implement some data management for a server so I will have HUGE data... I want more control with this so I could spare some harddisk's life.

Comment: Look at `mmap()` flag `MAP_LOCKED` or `mlock()` to stop pages being written out. The latter needs CAP_IPC_LOCK privilege.

Comment: @meuh AFAIK this is to prevent page out, but not to prevent flushing dirty pages.

Comment: Is there a way to, perhaps, manually control (to some extent) page linking, i.e. virtual page addressing, so I could "merge" the "mmap"-ed page with another page and thereby copy content to the file but without using ```memcpy```?

Answer (score 0):

This is my idea to answer my own question. Could I map the file with `mmap` using `MAP_PRIVATE` flag and then, only when I want to write it to hard disk, map it again with `MAP_SHARED` and copy contents using `memcpy`? What do you think about this in terms of efficiency?